# .db? file unable to be opened?

Tags: database

I received what is supposed to be a database of Android apps today in the form of a .tar file, named metadata.tar. I unzipped, and get a file called "metadata" that has no file extension (eg. the "file type" is "file".) When I open in Excel, row 1 says "metadata.db", and then says SQLite Format 3. Here's a screencap: http://tinypic.com/r/t8ov9x/6

So I figured its a .db file. Tried to open in MS Access, didn't work. Tried to open in SQLite Database Browser version 2.0b1, and it says "An Error Occurred: file is not an SQLite 3 Database."

Any suggestions on how to open this file? Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure that you opened the original file with the SQLite database browser. Excel and MS Access might have corrupted the file after you tried to open it.

Comment: Tried, still nothing. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Have you tried another sql browser?

Comment: Any particular favorites you'd like me to try? :) And do you have any more ideas as to what could be causing the problem?

Comment: You could try [SQLite Administrator](http://download.orbmu2k.de/download.php?id=19). Otherwise try a simple search. (just found this list, maybe one of them work: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/629-graphical-interfaces-for-sqlite )

Comment: Yeah still nothing... Saying "unable to perform this operation on a closed dataset". :(

Comment: than I have no idea :/ maybe you should ask the developer who send you the database?!

Answer (score 0):

In linux, you can try:

```
file metadata.db
```

file will determine the file type.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on Windows 7, sorry.

Comment: Using Access and Excel, it should be kind of obvious :)

Comment: Well yeah, it's a .db file, I'm assuming. Just still don't know how to open it into some sort of read-able state! :/